# swagger 2.0 - return a list/array instead of dict

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, swagger-codegen

I can't seem to find any info online about this, and I am not sure if this is possible with Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0.
I've created my specification and I want to return my data using flask and python with a list using the generated models. Here is my model:

```
  MyList:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
    uniqueItems: true
```

In the generated model, I don't see a `from_list` function, so this is where I am not sure if this is possible. I am not sure if I always have to return the responses with a dict? If that is the case, can I return a dict and then a list? My data is dynamic, so each time it may change when I query.

```
class MyList(Model):
    """NOTE: This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program.

    Do not edit the class manually.
    """

    def __init__(self):  # noqa: E501
        """MyList - a model defined in Swagger

        """
        self.swagger_types = {
        }

        self.attribute_map = {
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, dikt) -> 'MyList':
        """Returns the dict as a model

        :param dikt: A dict.
        :type: dict
        :return: The MyList of this MyList.  # noqa: E501
        :rtype: MyList
        """
        return util.deserialize_model(dikt, cls)
```

When I try to return the data using the model, it does not allow me to...

`return MyList(output)`

`TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

However, if I return the data without using the model, it is fine...
`return output`

Really not sure why this is, like I said, not sure if this is possible, if it's not is it possible in OpenAPI 3.0?

Comment: `MyList.__init__()` only takes one positional argument - itself. You're also passing something called `output`. Did you mean to provide that to `from_dict()`, so `return MyList.from_dict(output)` (there should be no need to instantiate the class to access a class method).

Comment: Can that one positional argument not be the list though? I am confused here.

Comment: Not when it's also taking itself as a parameter. You'd have to define it as two: `def __init__(self, output):`, though you don't need to instantiate the class to call a class method.

Comment: Oh yes - I can actually see `def __init__` inside of the model now, it was inside of the class (I breezed over that...). I noticed it when comparing another model. I wonder why swagger has only defined it as one parameter. It must because of the specification that I've written right?